# Async tasks disappearing

Tags: vb.net, task

I'm creating a lot of tasks like this:

```
Public Sub RequestAsync()
    Dim wc As New Net.WebClient
    CompleteTask = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(GetUrl())
    Dim CompleteAction As Action(Of Tasks.Task(Of String)) = AddressOf CompleteAsync
    CompleteTask.ContinueWith(CompleteAction)
End Sub
```

And I'm keeping track of how many concurrent tasks there are(outside this sub), limiting them to 10. When I call RequestAsync(), I increment the counter and when CompleteAction is called, it decrements the counter.

99.98% of them finish correctly, some are expected to fail due to whatever network failure in which case they get rescheduled. However, the remaining 0.02% disappear and are never heard from again. As far as I can tell, their threads are finished but they never call CompleteAction.

Is this normal behavior? Is there any way to guarantee that I get a notification when the task goes poof?

Answer (score 0):

You need always observe a `Task` for possible exceptions.
Use `Await` keyword to unwrap the task to underlying result.
When you use `Await` code execution will be moved to the caller of `RequestAsync` method and returned back here when `DownloadStringTaskAsync` completed.
Change your method to `Async`

```
Public Async Function RequestAsync() As Task
    Dim wc As New Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = Await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(GetUrl())
    'Check for result here
End Function
```

`Task` wrap all exceptions happened during processing and in the instance of `AggregateException`.
Exception will be thrown only when `Task` was observed